# The service class "WBSer_RwCnt.Rw_Count" does not comply to one or more requirements of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification

Tags: java, web-services

```
package WBSer_RwCnt;


import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.sql.Statement;

public class Rw_Count {

  public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {

    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/hospital_data";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "mysql";

    Class.forName(driver); // load MySQL driver
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    return conn;
  }

  public static int countRows(Connection conn, String tableName) throws SQLException {

    // select the number of rows in the table
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    int rowCount = -1;
    try {
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName);
      // get the number of rows from the result set
      rs.next();
      rowCount = rs.getInt(1);
    } finally {
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
    }
    return rowCount;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection conn = null;
    try {
      conn = getConnection();
      String tableName = "hospital_status";
      System.out.println("tableName=" + tableName);
      System.out.println("conn=" + conn);
      System.out.println("rowCount=" + countRows(conn, tableName));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    } finally {
      // release database resources
      try {
        conn.close();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error --->

```
The method "getConnection" on the service class "WBSer_RwCnt.Rw_Count" uses a data type, "java.sql.Connection", that is not supported
```

When i compile it without creating it as webservice it works correctly
but when i make it as web service it gives output as

Output --->

```
WBSer_RwCnt.Rw_CountSoapBindingStub@121a412b
```

Please Help !

#### Next Try

So this is what i have done after what you have said even then it gives following errors

Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/hospital_data
```

Message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/hospital_data
```

```java
package WBSer_RwCnt;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.sql.Statement;

public class Rw_Count {

public static int countRows() throws SQLException {

// select the number of rows in the table

Statement stmt = null;

ResultSet rs = null;

System.out.println("ram");

String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/hospital_data";

String username = "root";

String password = "mysql";

try {

    Class.forName(driver);

}
 catch (ClassNotFoundException e1)
 {

    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    e1.printStackTrace();

}

// load MySQL driver

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

int rowCount = -1;

try {

  stmt = conn.createStatement();

  rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hospital_status");

  // get the number of rows from the result set

  rs.next();

  rowCount = rs.getInt(1);

}

catch (Exception e) 

{
    e.printStackTrace();

    System.exit(1);

  }

finally {

  rs.close();

  stmt.close();

  conn.close();

}

return rowCount;

}

}
```

i have the added all jar files including the java mysql connectors

Comment: Please format your code and ask relevant questions.

Comment: (a) When you post code, you should format it as code by selecting all of it and clicking on the `{}`. (b) More importantly: you didn't ask a question, and didn't point out where the error occurs. Please use the `edit` link below your question and improve your question, or it will probably be closed rather quickly.

Comment: Making a class into a web service means you are allowing remote users to call the methods in that class, and get the result. What do you expect the remote user to get from running the `getConnection()` method?

Comment: so as to get the connection in conn that would be needed to call  public static int countRows(Connection conn, String tableName) by System.out.println("rowCount=" + countRows(conn, tableName));

Comment: RealSkeptic can you please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to be a full answer as I'm not exactly sure about the tools you are using to compile the web service, but anyway, here goes:

Basically, a connection is something that is only valid on a particular machine. If it's a TCP/IP connection, it consists of two pairs: source host and port, and target host and port. If it's a Linux socket, then it is an entry in that particular machine's directory tree.

A database connection is usually built on one of those constructs, so it, too, is particular to a machine.

Therefore, it doesn't make sense to pass a `Connection` object to the user who calls your method from some remote machine. And since it doesn't make sense, the JAX-RPC standard does not include a serialization for `Connection`, and that's why it fails.

Your problem is that you have designed your method such that it accepts a connection as a parameter, and uses that connection to access the database. This works OK locally, but is not a good design for a remote service.

Instead, your method should acquire the connection internally. The remote user should access just the `countRows` method, with the name of the table, and `countRows` should call `getConnection`, use the connection, and the close it.

You shouldn't have a main method in a web service. And the `getConnection` method should be changed from `public` to `private`, so that `countRows` can access it. When it is private, I believe the web service compiler will not complain about it because it doesn't have to create a serialization for it.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum. You should not create an answer if it is not really an answer to your problem. Instead, you should edit your question, write something like "**Edit**: My code is now ... and I get these results ... and it is not good because ...". Please do that before your aswer-that-is-not-an-answer is deleted by the community. Also make sure to properly format all your code by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` button.

Comment: i have edited it now please fix the above mentioned error for me